# MongoDB Creating document and on success create another document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, document

I am working on application using Node.js and MongoDB. I have a particular use case wherein I create a new user and on success add the user's ObjectId into another collection called 'cities' by fetching the user's city if not existing or create a new one and append User's ObjectId to Subscriber's List field of the city document. 
The Schemas look like below:

```
CitiesSchema: 
var CitiesSchema = new Schema({
  City:{
    type: String
  },
  SubscribersList: [{type: Schema.ObjectId}]
});

User Schema:
var UsersSchema = new Schema({
  emailId: {
    type: String,
    required: 'Mandatory field'
  },
  city: {
    type: String
  },
  subscribedOn: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  lastEmailSent: {
    type: Date,
    default: null
  },
  isActive: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: true
  }
});
```

Please let me know how I can tackle this in the cleanest way possible or is there any design pattern I need to follow ?

Comment: are you using `mongoose`?

Comment: yes I am using mongoose

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `then` notation to continue processing **after** you have created your `User`. Like this

```
UserSchema.create({
    emailId: 'email@exmaple.com',
    city: 'Rome'
  })
  .then(user => {
    // For example if you want to push to the city of the user

    CityScema.update({
      City: user.city
    }, {
      $push: {
        SubscribersList: user._id
      }
    }).then(() => {
      res.sendStatus(200);
    }).catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));

  }).catch(err => {
    // Handle your errors here
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Make sure you check the [Mongoose docs on Models](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/models.html) for more information